# combining st_contains with st_buffer gives very slow query

Tags: postgis, sql, buffer, query

I have a layer with roads (4000 features) and a layer with routes (80 features). I want to select every road located on a route, combined with the route-type.

Normaly I would use `select road.geom, road.id, route.type from road, route where st_contains(route.geom, road.geom)`.

Because the routes are not properly digitized I need to buffer the routes to select all roads contained by a route.  So when I do `select road.geom, road.id, route.type from road, route where st_contains(st_buffer(route.geom, 3), road.geom)` the query keeps running for a long time without result.

How can I make this query running faster?

Comment: Are you buffering by 3 degrees or is it meters?

Comment: 3 meter.  The CRS is epsg:31370

Answer (score 1):

Ensuring the geom is spatially indexed in the road and route tables will be essential to the speed of this query.

Assuming this is already in place I would recommend trying ST_DWithin which 'Returns true if the geometries are within the specified distance of one another.'

```
ST_DWithin(route.geom, road.geom, 3);
```

To ensure only geometries that are fully within the specified distance, [ST_DFullyWithin](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DFullyWithin.html) can be used instead.

```
ST_DFullyWithin(route.geom, road.geom, 3);
```

Comment: The problem with ST_DWithin is the same as using ST_Intersects.  It selects roads that are intersecting and not just are IN the perimeter of 3 meters

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that requirement. In that case use ST_DFullyWithin instead

Comment: I tried ST_DFullyWithin and I get no results...

Comment: Does adjusting the distance bring in any results? I don't know what the dataset is like, so I can't tell if that's an expected result or not.

Comment: when I increase the distance to 100, then I get 3 results

Comment: Using ST_LongestLine or ST_MaxDistance will shed some light on the distances between your geometries. My theory is that the route elements will be made up of numerous road elements, and therefore while a road element might be fully within 3 metres of a route element, the full extent of a route element will be further than 3 metres away from the road element. Perhaps the creation of a buffered route table with spatial index will be the best method to then perform st_contains

Comment: ST_Buffer is not a true buffer.  It approximates a buffer so you could get additional answers or fewer than what you should be getting.   ST_DFullyWithin and ST_DWiwhtin on the other hand would give you behavior like a true buffer.  The extent of a route doesn't need to be fully within the extent of the radius for the line to be considered fully within, so I think something else is wrong here and doing an index of buffer is not the best solution.  How many records do you get with your buffer solution?  Can you provide a sample dataset?

Comment: here is a link to the data (exported to shp from postgis): https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cnw4xlxv17tvsis/AAAwsUsH-Q-9vrZgLa2sNYkoa?dl=0